# Custom markup in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, wysiwyg, ckeditor4.x

I'm using CKEditor v4 and need to create markup that is not exactly HTML, but it's close (the output is a directive for something other than a browser). Specifically, I need to pick a font name from a dropdown and when applied use this as the HTML: `<f Helvetica>My text</f>`.

I believe I need a new `style` object, but from what I have so far, the result always shows the attribute with an empty value (`<f Helvetica="">My text</f>`).

This is the best I've come up with so far:

```
new CKEDITOR.style({element: 'f', attributes: {'MyFontName':null}}).buildPreview()
```

which results in

```
<f MyFontName=""></f>
```

What must be done to get the output I'm looking for, without the empty value? I see there is a CKEDITOR.style.addCustomHandler method. If this what must be used, please provide an example. The documentation doesn't provide much detail on this.